# I want to convert csv data to xlsx file data and upload in aws and get url

Tags: javascript, node.js

here I'm converting json to csv now i want to convert this csv file to xlsx data and upload it to AWS  and get the link

```
Convert CSV to XLSX
const xlsxFilePath = 'path/to/transaction_data.xlsx';
await csvtoxlsx.writeToFile(xlsxFilePath, csvData);

Read the XLSX file
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(xlsxFilePath);
```

I'm getting an error in writeToFile and cannot install the npm package csvtoxlsx.

Comment: Npm package `csvtoxlsx` is not actively maintained maybe you can find other package.

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: Reading the tags: How can it be fastify and express?

Answer (score 0):

Try with those new packages.

`npm install csvtojson xlsx`

```
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

app.get('/api/csv-to-xlsx', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const csvFilePath = '/path/to/your/csv/file.csv'; // Replace with the actual path to your CSV file
    const jsonArray = await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonArray);
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Sheet1');
    const xlsxFilePath = '/path/to/save/xlsx/file.xlsx'; // Replace with the desired path to save the XLSX file
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, xlsxFilePath);

    // Upload to S3 in here

    res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'CSV to XLSX conversion completed' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'An error occurred during conversion' });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.convertArrayToCSV = (data, headers) => {
const csvRows = [];
const headerValues = headers.map((header) => header.label);
csvRows.push(headerValues.join(","));
data.forEach((object) => {
const values = headers.map((header) => {
  if (typeof header.value === "function") {
    return header.value(object);
  }
  return object[header.value];
});
csvRows.push(values.join(","));
});
const csvData = csvRows.join("\n");
return csvData;
};
let fileName = `Transaction_report_${req?.headers?.daterange}`;

    const csvData = convertArrayToCSV(
      data?.data?.transactions,
      downloadFields
    );
    console.log(csvData, "csvDATA");
     
    const workbook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    const worksheet = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet([]);

    const rows = [];
    let hasHeader = false;
    streamifier
      .createReadStream(csvData)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("data", (data) => {
        if (!hasHeader) {
          const headerRow = Object.keys(data);
          console.log(headerRow, "asjhgdghasdh");
          xlsx.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [headerRow], {
            origin: 0,
          });
          hasHeader = true;
        }
        const rowData = Object.values(data);
        console.log(rowData, "asdahjsd");
        rows.push(rowData);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        xlsx.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, rows, { origin: 1 });
        xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Sheet 1");

        const outputFilePath = "output1254.xlsx";
        xlsx.writeFile(workbook, outputFilePath);
        console.log("Conversion complete!");
      });
```